# Angle formed between a satellite, a ground station, and then another Satellite

Tags: satellite

I am trying to check my work on calculating the angle between two sats and a ground station observing those two sats. I have the az and elevation angles to each sat from the ground station. What would be the equation to get the angle Sat1-GS-Sat2?

I know that it uses the law of Cosines, but not sure if I was using the correct equation.  Here is what I am using:

Angle = acos((abs(sin("V_Sat_1_EL")*sin("V_Sat_2_EL")))+(cos("V_Sat_1_EL")*cos("V_Sat_2_EL")*cos(abs("V_Sat_2_AZ"-"V_Sat_1_AZ"))))

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This figure from
[Wikipedia:Spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines)
applies if the ground station is at the center of the sphere, 
**u** is the ground station's zenith, and **v** and **w** are the apparent positions of the satellites as seen from the ground station.

[image: spherical triangle diagram]

Then ***a*** and ***b*** are the satellites' zenith angles, i.e. 90° minus their elevation angles.
***C*** is the difference between the satellites' azimuths, and ***c*** is the angle you want.

Using the cosine rule for sides
$$\cos c = \cos a \cos b  + \sin a  \sin b  \cos C$$
and the rules for sines and cosines of complementary angles,
the expression in the question looks correct if the absolute value operations are omitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need angles, you need interior angle triangle forumula, all angles in interior sum is equal to  180° . only you need  Angle Sat 1 + Angle Sat 2 + Angle Sat 1-2 = 180°, if you need  distances A, B , C you need use polar coordenates. lat, long and elevation.

Comment: I don't know the angle between the two satellites, only the AZ and EL to each from the GS.  Think of the GS as the center of a sphere, and the two satellites are points on that sphere and I have two angles from the center of the sphere that give the position of where each Satellite is on the surface of the sphere.  I need the angle that is formed by that GS looking at each Satellite.

Comment: AZ is Azimuth , and EL is Elevation ? because Azimuth is a angular meassure

Comment: I should clarify.  I know the AZ (angle) and Elevation Angle to each.  So imagine my Ground Station is sitting at the center.  My AZ to one satellite is the angle I rotate myself to look at it and then my elevation is how high I need to look at it.  I have both of those for each Satellite.  I need to figure out the angle that is formed between the first satellite, the Ground Station, and then the second satellite.  I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: This answer is for Euclidian planar geometry but the question is about spherical trigonometry; triangles drawn on the surface of a unit sphere.